# Xamarin IOS NFCNdefReaderSession.ReadingAvailable is false

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, nfc

I came across problem with setup NFC reader on Xamarin IOS. Example of configurationn is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/introduction-to-ios11/corenfc

After launching application the NFCNdefReaderSession.ReadingAvailable is always false and in device logs:

```
[NFCNDEFReaderSession beginSession]:255  error:Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service named com.apple.nfcd.service.corenfc was invalidated from this process." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.nfcd.service.corenfc was invalidated from this process.}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In IOS project settings -> IOS Bundle Singing -> Custom  Entitlements - it was blank in my project. Just set it to your Entitlements.plist